# YTSearchbar term connect to Searchbar

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, react-redux, searchbar

I'm beginner of react. While I'm making my own youtube application, I wanted to connect YTSearchbar term to Search bar on my app.

here

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import VideoList from './components/VideoList';

const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyA5JE7QYKFSlEnRij3tqxYS2XWqG0Au20o';


class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { videos: [] };

    YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: "dong"}, (videos) => {
        this.setState({videos}); //access videos on state
      });
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>DongHyun's Youtube Channel</h1>
        <SearchBar />
        <VideoList videos={this.state.videos} />
      </div>
    );
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

So if I put whatever in term: "SOMETHING", then I want it to automatically goes into

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

class SearchBar extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { word: '' };
}

render() {
return (
    <div>
     <input 
     value = {this.state.word}
     onChange={(e) =>this.setState({word: e.target.value})}/>
     <Button color="secondary">Search</Button>
    </div>
    );
}
}

export default SearchBar;
```

this search bar input.

please help! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First, clean up your reference to `React.Component` by using ES6 syntax. Instead, go back up to your import statement and refactor it like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

This keeps your code consistent as you did do this in your `App` component. Don't forget to turn change from `React.Component` to just `Component`. Yes, its syntactic sugar, but it does make your code look cleaner and consistent.

Second, let's talk handling user events inside of `SearchBar` component. You can defined a method called:

```
onInputChange() {

}
```

right below your `render()` method. An alternative method name would be `handleInputChange()`, it's up to you. So generally, it starts with `on` or `handle`, then the name of the element you are watching a change for, in your case an input element. So, whenever the input changes, JavaScript will run the code you are going to place inside the method above.

Next, you want to pass that method to the input element. So you see how you have: `<input onChange={(e) =>this.setState({word: e.target.value})}/>`, you were sort of on the right track. Refactor it like so:

`<input onChange={this.onInputChange}/>`

All HTML input elements emit a change event whenever the user interacts with them, thats a normal HTML thing in the browser. To tap into a normal browser event, all we have to do is reference the event handler via `this.onInputChange` within the curly braces as you see above.

And as you know we wrap it in curly braces because we are inserting JavaScript variables inside of JSX.

So we create a new input element and pass it a property of `onChange` with a value of `this.onInputChange`.

Go ahead and declare the event handler like so and then you will have to pass `event` as an argument inside the event handler like so:

```
onInputChange(event) {

}
```

All browser events that get triggered by html elements, an event handler is always called an `event` object. The `event` object describes the context about the event that occurred. In this case, since its an input element, you can use the `event` object to gain access to the value of the input, in other words, what text was inputted to trigger the change, whether it was "SOMETHING" or "something else".

You can test that out by console logging `event.target.value` like so:

```
onInputChange(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
}
```